# Прилагательное от альпака

Tags: суффиксы-прилагательных

Существует ли прилагательное от АЛЬПАКА?

Comment: В словарях слово альпачий (ср. барсук - барсучий) пока отсутствует (до недавнего времени в нём не было практической потребности), но в фермерской и торговой среде прилагательное  стало употребляться сравнительно широко: альпачья ферма (шерсть, семейство и т. п.).

Answer (score 1):

[**альпаковый**](https://gallicismes.academic.ru/1915/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9)
Альпаговый, -ая, -ое; альпаковый, -ая, -ое
Исторический словарь галлицизмов русского языка

*На нем были поношенный **альпаковый** сюртук и серые брюки; бороду он сбрил, оставив только эспаньолку и усы.*
С. Моэм

*Он носил черный **альпаковый** полуперденчик с воздушными веревочными петлями, туфли на плоской подошве и косичку.*
Г. Миллер

*Доктор был одет в черный блестящий, так называемый **альпаговый**, пиджак, белый жилет, серые в полоску штаны, и на голове у него была из твердой соломы невысокая шляпа — так называемое канотье.*
Ю. Олеша

Comment: _Исторический словарь галлицизмов_ Любопытно. В одном из выпусков "Русского языкознания" сказано, что это "латиноамериканизм прежних периодов заимствования".

Answer (score 0):

*альпакский*

В Тверской и Орловской области есть деревни с наименовнием *Альпаково*.

*альпакский дворик*,  *альпакский сельсовет*.

Еще говорят - *альпакский магазин*, где продают товары из шерсти альпаки.

Comment: Сельсовет в материалах по истории Тверской Губернии - _Альпаковский_. "Альпакский" по типу словообразования напоминает больше о связи с неким этносом (коряки - Корякский округ) - в гугле всего три находки на отдельно взятое слово. В шутку можно сказать и "альпакалиптический", но естественнее всего выглядит _альпачий_ (максимум совпадений по гуглу - много страниц)

Comment: Суп из ламы - *ламский суп*, а из альпаки как назвать? :)

Comment: _из шерсти альпаки_ Запомните, пожалуйста, что "альпака" не склоняется. Употребляется в мужском или женском роде, если речь идёт о животном, но может обозначать название шерсти или ткани — тогда это средний род.

Comment: Думаю, что слово "альпачий" приживётся как пароним (крокодиловый предмет одежды/обуви - крокодилий хвост, слёзы и т.п) - для обозначения того, что ближе к зверю, а не к продукту из ткани, которая из его же шерсти.

Comment: От альпаково - альпаковский. От альпака - альпакский. Альпачий - это притяжательное (сомнительной нормативности, просторечное, видимо), если альпака - животное (название или кличка). https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0 Что вы сказать хотели по сути вопроса - не понял.